# What are the default settings of addplot in pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

Consider the following code from [PGFPlots Gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) which draws multiple plots with the names of d2, d3, d4, d5 and d6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel={Degrees of freedom},
    ylabel={$L_2$ Error}
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (5,8.312e-02)    (17,2.547e-02)   (49,7.407e-03)
    (129,2.102e-03)  (321,5.874e-04)  (769,1.623e-04)
    (1793,4.442e-05) (4097,1.207e-05) (9217,3.261e-06)
};

\addplot coordinates{
    (7,8.472e-02)    (31,3.044e-02)    (111,1.022e-02)
    (351,3.303e-03)  (1023,1.039e-03)  (2815,3.196e-04)
    (7423,9.658e-05) (18943,2.873e-05) (47103,8.437e-06)
};

\addplot coordinates{
    (9,7.881e-02)     (49,3.243e-02)    (209,1.232e-02)
    (769,4.454e-03)   (2561,1.551e-03)  (7937,5.236e-04)
    (23297,1.723e-04) (65537,5.545e-05) (178177,1.751e-05)
};

\addplot coordinates{
    (11,6.887e-02)    (71,3.177e-02)     (351,1.341e-02)
    (1471,5.334e-03)  (5503,2.027e-03)   (18943,7.415e-04)
    (61183,2.628e-04) (187903,9.063e-05) (553983,3.053e-05)
};

\addplot coordinates{
    (13,5.755e-02)     (97,2.925e-02)     (545,1.351e-02)
    (2561,5.842e-03)   (10625,2.397e-03)  (40193,9.414e-04)
    (141569,3.564e-04) (471041,1.308e-04) (1496065,4.670e-05)
};
\legend{$d2$,$d3$,$d4$,$d5$,$d6$}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result is:
[image]

Now, I want to only have the plot d4. So, I removed the unneeded section as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel={Degrees of freedom},
    ylabel={$L_2$ Error}
]
\addplot coordinates{
    (9,7.881e-02)     (49,3.243e-02)    (209,1.232e-02)
    (769,4.454e-03)   (2561,1.551e-03)  (7937,5.236e-04)
    (23297,1.723e-04) (65537,5.545e-05) (178177,1.751e-05)
};
\legend{$d4$}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the final result for d4 in the above figures are different, e.g. d4 is brown and blue in the first and second figure respectively. The reason is that in the first figure, d4 is the third plot, while in the second figure, d4 is the first plot. What I need is to have completely same `\addplot` settings for d4 in both figures. More precisely, d4 in the second figure must have same mark options and color as it has in the first figure, e.g. d4 should be also brown in the second figure. I tried to manually add `mark` and `color` to `\addplot` command like `\addplot[color=brown, mark options={fill=brown}, ...]`, but at the end of the day, I could not get the desired output. So, I am thinking if we can find the default settings of `\addplot` for d4 in the first figure and use them in the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is determined by the default `cycle list`, which is called `color`, and is described in the `pgfplots` manual, on the bottom of page 217 (in the manual for version 1.17, dated 29 Feb 2020), in the section called 4.7.7 *Cycle Lists – Options Controlling Line Styles*. There you'll find that the third entry in that cycle list is

```
brown!60!black,every mark/.append style={fill=brown!80!black},mark=otimes*\\
```

(The `\\` indicates the end of that entry in the list.)

Another option though is to use `cycle list shift`, which lets you jump ahead in the cycle list without adding any plots. Add `\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=2}` just before your `\addplot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel={Degrees of freedom},
    ylabel={$L_2$ Error}
]

\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=2}
\addplot coordinates{
    (9,7.881e-02)     (49,3.243e-02)    (209,1.232e-02)
    (769,4.454e-03)   (2561,1.551e-03)  (7937,5.236e-04)
    (23297,1.723e-04) (65537,5.545e-05) (178177,1.751e-05)
};
\legend{$d4$}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a minor thing which confused me, in your default color code there are two `mark` options at the end, but only the first one, `mark=otimes*` is enough for me.

Comment: @Patris Oops, sorry. That was just a copy-paste error, I must have copied a bit more from the manual than I had intended. Will fix in a few seconds.